# What are these lines doing? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to translate a small program from MATLAB to Python. I do not have MATLAB to run the code and see the output. Anyways, the program has a weird section that I do not know how to interpret correctly.

Here is that part of the code:

```
randn('state',2) 
for ncase=1:3
sumex=0;
```

I know `randn` gives a matrix with normally distributed numbers - but what does it have to do with the `for` loop - and `'state'`? I notice there is no semicolon after it.

I am guessing `'state'` is the name of the matrix, and it is not initiated - nor referenced anywhere else in the code.

If I commented out `randn('state',2)` is it going to change the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out `randn('state',2)` will have an effect on the code and its output as `randn('state',2)` is old **[discouraged](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/updating-your-random-number-generator-syntax.html)** MATLAB syntax to specify the random number generator to use with `randn` and to seed it.

You could replace it simply with your own method to seed your own random number generator of choice in python.

---

`for ncase=1:3` will loop from `1` to `3` in increments of `1`. `ncase` will be `1` in the first iteration, `2` in the second iteration and `3` in the third and final iteration.

---

`sumex=0;` sets the variable `sumex` equal to 0.

Comment: Assuming random numbers are used in the code somewhere after the line `randn('state',2)` then commenting it out will have an effect on the code.  That is the old, and no longer recommended, way to set the seed of the random number generator.  (See [Replace Discouraged Syntaxes for rand and randn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/updating-your-random-number-generator-syntax.html)).  With that line in the code, the same (pseudo-)random number sequence will be used every time the code is run.  Without it a different (pseudo-)random sequence will be used each time.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Yes, you are correct. I had it that way in my head but just wrote it out wrong. I was distracted by the England v Wales rugby match :P I already had that link in your comment in my answer and an explanation of same. It was just the beginning of the answer I'd mixed up.

Comment: @IKavanagh would you like to add Phil's correction to your answer so I can give you the check mark. Thank you to both of you! I am gonna find how to fix the seed in mympy for Python now.

Comment: No, everything is clear to me now - but "little affect" may be confusing to others if they do not read the comment. I would prefer "fixes the seed vs does not fix the seed" ... Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: @EdvBeq I'll do that so. How's that?